# NIntegrate Cos[j x], from -pi to pi, with Method->"Trapezoidal" for j = multiples of 16

Tags: numerical-integration

The function
NIntegrate[Cos[j x], {x, -[Pi], [Pi]}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"] returns zero (as expected) for any value of j except multiples of 16. Any ideia if this is a bug and how to solve it?
[image]

Comment: You are aware of [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), yes? Ponder on the result of e.g. `ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Cos[16 x]}, {x, -π, π, 2 π/16}]]` and this might help you realize why you're getting those anomalous results for those particular values.

Comment: Helpful tool here: you can use `EvaluationMonitor` to get the points used by NIntegrate to see what's going on: `Reap[NIntegrate[Cos[16 x], {x, -Pi, 0, Pi}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", 
   EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Cos[16 x]}]]][[2, 1]]`